# JSON jackson creator: Default Value and nice to have values

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have to build an json with mandatory fields, defaulted fields (if value is not set), and optional (not mandatory) fields. This class is used for de- and serialization. The final json should look different, if e.g. some not mandatory field is not set or a mandatory value is not set, but should be defaulted.

```
@JsonSnakeCase
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
public class TryoutJson {

    @JsonCreator
    public TryoutJson(
        @NotBlank
        @JsonProperty("mandatory")
        final String mandatory,
        @...WHAT HERE TO set to default?
        @JsonProperty("valueDefaultedTo5IfNotSet")
        final String valueDefaultedTo5IfNotSet,
        @... What here to set just if value is given?
        @JsonProperty("thisFieldIsNotMAndatory")
        final String thisFieldIsNotMAndatory,
    ) throws IllegalArgumentException
    {
     //....
    }

}
```

For example this json strings should be created in the used constructor:

```
{"mandatory":"mandatoryValue","valueDefaultedTo5IfNotSet":"5"} is the same like {"mandatory":"mandatoryValue"}
```

or

```
{"mandatory":"mandatoryValue","valueDefaultedTo5IfNotSet":"2","thisFieldIsNotMAndatory":"ValueXY"}
```

Is it possible to have only one constructor for all this settings? I dont want do build several constructors for each possible variant.
If important, this imports are used:

```
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
```

Comment: Can you not set the mandatory properites to their default value when you create the object?

Comment: I want to deserialize the json above, but there are several different variants of the json.

Comment: You have two ways around it: 1. use alternate constructors; 2. use a builder